# How to get all rows matching a determined month

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want get all rows of a determined month, but when I create my database save the date with this syntax:  `1477800000` (this is my date "2016-10-30")

My query is:

```
SELECT * from Aula where EXTRACT(month from dateCreated) = 4
```

I need to query using month and year In my example it is only with month. How can I query with month and year?

I get this error:

> 2019-10-24 10:24:16.699649-0400 project[1840:36099] DB Error: 1 "near "from": syntax error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`strftime`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and `DATETIME` for this.  Use `DATETIME(dateCreated,'unixepoch')` to convert your integer into a `datetime`, or use `strftime('%m', 1477800000, 'unixepoch')` which will convert the date without needing to use `DATETIME`.

```
SELECT * 
from Aula 
where strftime('%m', dateCreated, 'unixepoch') = '04'     -- month
  and strftime('%Y', dateCreated, 'unixepoch') = '2016'  -- year
```

where `%m` is the format for month and returns 01-12, and `%Y` is the format for year (note uppercase). This is detailed in the docs I linked to above.

> The strftime() routine returns the date formatted according to the format string specified as the first argument.

**Note** your date is indeed `2016-10-30` but you're looking for month 4 (April) so that date (`1477800000`) won't appear in your results.

Comment: this is my date 1477800000 (this is my date "2016-10-30")

Comment: @becauseR What exactly is the contents of your `dateCreated` column?

Comment: @becauseR updated my answer.  You need to convert the integer to a datetime

Comment: @Shawn dateCreated contents these dates 1477800000

Comment: @becauseR should be `strftime('%m', dateCreated, 'unixepoch')` then. (Assuming that number is the Unix time in seconds)

Comment: @Shawn i only want to get all rows of the a month and year, I don't want to get all the years

Comment: @becauseR I've added year filter to my answer